# pulling dateTime back a few hours (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some SMS messages that are being rendered 6 hours later than they should be.  I am thinking there is a timezone issue, but i want to at the minimum pull it back the 6 hours and get that pushed out before I go ahead with finding the root of the bug.

However I've been having a very frustrating experience trying to change this.

I've tried making a change within my view which is looking like so. The crux of the bus is on the `message.date_sent`

```
        - @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.list({:to => @player.phone})[0,5].each do |message|
          %tr
            %td= message.date_sent
            %td= message.from
            %td= message.to
            %td= message.status
            %td
              = message.sid
              %br
              = message.body
```

Initially I thought the solution could be in the view, and went toward `td= message.date_sent(-6.hours)` however I run into errors that the `-` is not a defined method.

In my controller I tried creating something like

```
def minus6
  -6.hours
end
```

and then tried placing that in the end of my view like `td= message.date_sent.minus6` However I again run into `undefined method 'minus6' for "Wed, 27 Jan 2016 20:22:34"`

If anybody could help me with this, I would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the ActiveSuport helpers

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-ago

```
6.hours.ago(message.date_sent)
```